# Make uploaded files to S3 public by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I have tried a bunch of suggested solutions from Stack Overflow and other sites, but to no avail.

I have a bucket which I am uploading files to from a web page using one of the IAM accounts that I have created. These uploaded files are located within dynamically created folders within my parent bucket.

I need to ensure that any folder which is created along with any uploaded files held within the newly created folder are all public so any user can see them and download them.

Currently I am using the "S3 browser" application however it is not allowing me to download any of the uploaded files (although I can actually see them).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 26):

Create a Bucket Policy on that specific bucket, which grants `GetObject` permissions for anonymous users. Replace "examplebucket" with the name of the bucket. You can add the [Bucket Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2) in the Amazon S3 Management Console, in the Permissions section.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"AddPerm",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: For future searcher - Also note that the version number is Amazon's version number - Do not change it. If you try changing it, you will get - "The policy must contain a valid version string - undefined"

Comment: There's also a 'policy generator' on S3 console where you can use this policy as a guide, provide * for principal, * for the keys in the resource ARN, and generate a new policy. That way even if the version is out of date, you'll get a working policy

Comment: Not anymore works. Looks like they have deprecated 'Principal' field.

Error : ```This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies```

Comment: @Vineeth The above policy is a **Bucket Policy** that is placed on a bucket. If it is being used in an IAM policy, then the principal should be removed because it automatically applies to the IAM entity on which it was placed.

Comment: Got it. Thanks mahn